# Im trying to print the "J" in initial = dotmatrix.dotJ("J")

Tags: python-3.x

I have a project where I build a dotmatrix module and then import it into another program that will print out my initials. I have it done to the point where it will print out my initials, but it won't print the "J" in the

```
initial = dotmatrix.dotJ("J")
```

It will just print the "*". I have defined in my module:

```
def dotJ(char):
    """Creates a capital J in 7 x 7 dots"""
    dotJ =  "      * \n"
    dotJ += "      * \n"
    dotJ += "      * \n"
    dotJ += "      * \n"
    dotJ += " *    * \n"
    dotJ += " *    * \n"
    dotJ += "  ***   \n"
    return dotJ
```

where I have the *, I want it to print out whatever is called for in the

initial = dotmatrix.dotJ("J")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to define your `dotJ` variable with a star and then `replace` the star with the character:

```
def dotJ(char):
    """Creates a capital J in 7 x 7 dots"""
    dotJ =  "      * \n"
    dotJ += "      * \n"
    dotJ += "      * \n"
    dotJ += "      * \n"
    dotJ += " *    * \n"
    dotJ += " *    * \n"
    dotJ += "  ***   \n"
    dotJ = dotJ.replace("*",char)
    return dotJ
```

You could also use a format string. But I suspect this would be less easy to read.

Comment: ya i have make my code pass in whatever character i tell it to do in my function. So if i tell it use "J" instead of "*" it will. Without going and changing my def from "*" to "J" manually

Comment: now that i have my program printing the way i want to, now I want to input a string to get the first intial, then take that output and look for the corresponding letter i have defined in a module that I imported. is that possible? – Jamie Schwiderski 16 hours ago